# Running tcpdump in the background linux

Tags: bash, stdout, io-redirection, stderr, tcpdump

Linux (Gentoo) and Linux (Redhat on AWS free)

I am a member of the pcap group and can run tcpdump as a non-root user.

I am trying to run a script the runs tcpdump in the background and send the output to a text file temp.txt. My script will create a file called temp.txt but `/usr/bin/tcpdump  -tttt` will not write to it.

I can run the script without nohup.

```
/usr/sbin/tcpdump -c 10 -tttt > `pwd`/temp.txt
```

Why will the nohup not work? The following is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#tpd-txt.sh
nohup /usr/sbin/tcpdump -c 10 -tttt > `pwd`/temp.txt > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: From the bash manual: "Redirections are processed in the order they appear,
       from left to right."  So your `> /dev/null` replaces `> \`pwd\`/temp.txt`, and standard output ends up redirected to `/dev/null`.  Perhaps you wanted to write `> \`pwd\`/temp.txt 2>/dev/null`?

Comment: Also, isn't `\`pwd\`/` redundant?  `> temp.txt 2>/dev/null` should do exactly the same thing.

Comment: I added `pwd`  because I am also trying to run this as shell_exec in a php script.  thanks

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @1885, that doesn't explain why you think you need `pwd`. Whatever or not you use it, the output file ends up in the current working directory (whatever it is in your PHP runtime, if that's the parent process).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
nohup /usr/sbin/tcpdump -c 10 -tttt 2>&1  >./temp.txt &
```

I am assuming you want to redirect standard error to output so it can be captured in logs.

Below is quick reference guide for output redirection in bash.

```
1>filename
 # Redirect stdout to file "filename."
1>>filename
  # Redirect and append stdout to file "filename."
2>filename
  # Redirect stderr to file "filename."
2>>filename
  # Redirect and append stderr to file "filename."
&>filename
  # Redirect both stdout and stderr to file "filename."
2>&1
  # Redirects stderr to stdout.
  # Error messages get sent to the same place as standard output.
```

Comment: If you want them both in the same log, reverse that ordering to be `>./temp.txt 2>&1` so you copy stdout to stderr **after** making stdout point to the file; the operations happen one at a time, left to right. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/055

Comment: Thank you so much for all the posts.  This has been very educational!  I have a better understanding of how things are being processed rather than just a copy and paste of someones code.

Comment: This worked on an AWS remote sever:  ```nohup /usr/sbin/tcpdump  -tttt > /dev/null 2>&1  >./temp12.txt &```

Comment: I looked for an explanation of  > ./temp.txt   I understand ./code.sh  replaces /home/user/code.sh   does >./temp.txt do the same. What is the difference between ./ and ~/?

Comment: `.` is currently working directory from where you are executing the script. `~` is root directory